# How can I retrieve the VM Agent status of an Azure VM using Azure CLI?

Tags: azure, command-line-interface

VM Agent Status:

[image]

How to retrieve the VM Agent status of an Azure VM? (not the Monitoring agent, this is not a extension)

I have tried using 'az vm show' with details but it is nowhere to be found. I could only see the status of the VM Agent in the portal, under VM properties (Ready or Not Ready normally).

Any way to retrieve this info from the Azure CLI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Retrieve the VM Agent status of an Azure VM?

I have a virtual machine with Agent status = ready.

[image]

You can use the below command to get the VM agent status.

**Command:**

```
 az vm get-instance-view --name <Your virtual machine name> --resource-group <Your resource group name> --query instanceView.vmAgent.statuses
```

**Output:**

```
[
  {
    "code": "ProvisioningState/succeeded",
    "displayStatus": "Ready",
    "level": "Info",
    "message": "Guest Agent is running",
    "time": "2023-05-23T07:39:21+00:00"
  }
]
```

[image]

**Reference:**
[az vm | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/vm?view=azure-cli-latest#az-vm-get-instance-view)